# Understanding Garbage Collection in android

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I Think i Need Some Help to Understand Garbage Collections, well i know garbage collection clears those who have no referrence from a live Thread, so for example i have a class that Decodes images like this:

```
 new ImageDecoder(MyImageView).Decode();
```

do i need to keep a reference to the ImageDecoder class and null it later, or it will recycle whenever i call MyImageView.setBackgroundResource(0);   ?

or whenever that i create a reference to a class and that Class adds tons of stacks, so whenever i do

```
   MyClass aClass;

    ...

   aClass = null;
```

Then the Heap Should be Freed From all Heap that Class Took according to the Articles, But It doesnt Happen in real life as i see , how is that working?

thanks alot;

Answer (score 0):

You cant controll in Java and same applies here. Assigning aClass = null doesnt mean GC will run immediately and free memory on heap. It will run when he thinks JVM is running out of memory and creation of new objects require more space then it may run which in case my stop your main thread and freeze your app.

[Oracle Java GC Basics](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

Comment: See forcing or through program when you do following like
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
it doesnt gurantee GC will run.